# Can db2 import or load be used to populate DashDB?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I'm looking to bulk loads millions of rows into a DashDB database.  After connecting using the DB2 CLI, I enter a command like:

```
db2 import from rowsToImport.csv of del insert into MY_TABLE
```

with results:

```
SQL0551N  "DASHXXX" does not have the required authorization or privilege to
perform operation "BIND" on object "NULLID.SQLUAJ19".  SQLSTATE=42501
```

Is this an inherent limitation with DashDB, or is something configured incorrectly on my client?  I get a similar message when trying `db2 load`:

```
SQL2019N  An error occurred while utilities were being bound to the database.
```

p.s. I'm aware of the rest client api for DashDB for loading data - I'm asking specifically how/if bulk loads can be done with the DB2 command line as an alternate option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21605372), the package NULLID.SQLUAJ19 belongs to one of the early DB2 10.1 fix packs, so I suspect your client version is 10.1. When attempting to execute the `IMPORT` command it needs to bind some packages of that older version, since dashDB is DB2 10.5, obvisouly.

You may want to try installing the latest DB2 client fix pack, as the necessary packages may be already bound in the database.

To verify that you could run `select pkgname from syscat.packages where pkgschema = 'NULLID' and pkgname like 'SQLUA%'` -- you should see "SQLUAK20", which seems to be the corresponding package in DB2 10.5.

If that doesn't work, your other option might be to move to a dedicated dashDB instance, as you won't have sufficient privileges to bind missing packages in the entry-level shared dashDB service.

Comment: That was it - upgrading to DB2 10.5 client did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As per [dashDB documentation](https://ibmdatawarehousing.wordpress.com/tag/bluemix/) you can use the [Command line processor plus (CLPPlus)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.clpplus.doc/doc/c0053823.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F3-6-2-1). It is included in the dashDB driver package and provides a command-line user interface that you can use to connect to the dashDB database, BLUDB. You can use CLPPlus to define, edit, and run statements, scripts, and commands. Please take also a look at [Connecting CLPPlus to the dashDB database](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connect_connecting_clpplus.html) to see how to connect and use the CLI.

Please note that in CLPPlus: IMPORT, EXPORT and LOAD commands have a restriction that processed files must be on the server: see [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.clpplus.doc/doc/c0054832.html?lang=en). So you should copy the input load file onto the remote server first with SCP. However SSH/SCP protocol should be blocked (not accessible) for a normal dashDB user.

Only geospatial data can be loaded from your local machine to dashDB, using [IDA LOADGEOSPATIALDATA command](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.clpplus.doc/doc/r0061932.html) in CLPPlus.
The file to be loaded in dashDB using the above command can be in the local file system, accessible to the CLPPlus user.

Alternative ways to do that are:

- dashDB REST API (as you already mentioned). See [Load delimited data using the REST API and cURL](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/docs/dashdb/rest-api/load-delimited-data-using-the-rest-api-and-curl/).
- load the csv directly from the dashDB dashboard on Bluemix. See [Loading data from the desktop into IBM dashDB](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/wp-content/uploads/sites/47/2015/07/loading-data-from-the-desktop-tutorial.pdf).
- load the csv using IBM Data Studio. See [dashDB large file load using IBM Data Studio](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/170415/dashdb-large-file-load-using-ibm-data-studio.html).

Comment: Hi @Umberto Manganiello, thanks for your answer.  I'm using the DB2 CLI which seems to be supported (see answer [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/25034/unable-to-load-large-csv-file-in-blu-acceleration-for-cloud/)). Can you confirm whether load / import are explicitly allowed/disallowed from the normal DB2 CLI (not CLPPlus) in DashDB?